# Foco en textbox en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un formapplication creado en C#, el cual espera un dato scaneado o digitado para hacer una busqueda, pero quiero que me haga la busqueda automatic si yo escaneo el numero. La busqueda automatic ya la hace pero solo si yo estoy posicionado en el textbox, al no estar posicionado en el textbox y yo escaneo, no pasa nada. Entonces lo que quiero es que lo que yo escanee se coloque en el textbox aunque no este posicionado en el.
Como lo podria hacer?
No tengo codigo sobre eso aun.
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega un evento al Form que detecte cuando se reciba una tecla

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object Sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (!textBox.Focused)
        {
            textBox.Focus();
            textBox.Text += e.KeyChar;
            // Move el cursor al final
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
        }
}
```

Tambien tienes que establecer la propiedad KeyPreview del formulario a True:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49496/discussion-on-answer-by-tuco-foco-en-textbox-en-c).

Comment: @MiquelColl la conversacion ya se habia continuado en un chat, ahora la conversacion en el chat manda a otro chat